# Symlink/Rename Overleaf Project Locally

Tags: git, symlink, overleaf

I have a few overleaf projects that have unreadable names, e.g., `5faa124ad2e10a34cb` and `5gbba78lkjs9910ls` that I've git-linked so that I can work locally from my machine.
However, it is difficult to remember that `5faa...` refers to project X and `5gbb...` refers to project Y.
Is there a way to rename the overleaf/git repos locally so that I can navigate to a readable directory, e.g.,

```
cd project-x
```

but actually end up in `path/to/5faa124ad2e10a34cbaskjd69` and similarly for project Y so that I can still use `git` commands?

I tried symlinking, e.g., `ln -s path/to/5faa124ad2e10a34cbaskjd69 path/to/project-x`. but then when I do `cd project-x`, my machine does not recognize it as a git repo.

---

**Edit**: I just tried git commit/pull on some test files from the symlinked folder, and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a git project is just a folder with a `.git` folder inside. You can rename the parent folder all you want, it won't affect your ability to run git commands inside.

To go a bit further, you can also tell git to clone a repository to another folder: `git clone https://some-repo.example.com/5faa124ad2e10a34cb my-folder` will clone that project into the new folder `my-folder`.

Once again, there is nothing magical about git repositories, they just contain a `.git` folder with the repository information and history inside, so you can move the folder around, pass it on a usb stick, etc. As long as the `.git` folder is preserved, you keep history and branching information. You can even clone it to a new location:

`git clone my-folder my-new-folder` will clone the repository under that new folder, with the `origin` remote pointing to the original folder. You can also put a git folder on a webserver, on a network drive, etc.